# Automatically resize array after popping any element in C++

Tags: c++

Is there any array type data structure (like vector, stack, queue etc) in c++ in which I can pop/delete an element from any index in such a way that the array will automatically resize itself?

**Example:**

```
int arr[]={2,5,8,10,6};
arr[2].pop();
```

And then the array will become like this:

```
arr[]={2,5,10,6};
```

Comment: -   `std::vector`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` has an `erase()` method that removes an element at a given position, and reduces the size of the array. The erase position is specified by an iterator, but it's trivial to add `n` to `begin()`, to get it.

Note, however, that `erase()`'s complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: Regarding the performance of `std::vector` - here's Herb Sutter at Build 2014 talking about prefetching and how amazingly quick it is to iterate over vectors: https://youtu.be/TJHgp1ugKGM?t=1410

Comment: I'm aware of the counter-intuitive performance of vectors, due to modern CPUs' caching. Still, doesn't change the fact that it's `O(n)`.